# How do I do a processor reset in C for a STM32F2

Tags: c

Hello I am a rookie C programmer, I have a problem with the RTC on my microcontroller it resets the date when I do a power reset, but does not update the date normally, I have followed the correct initialisation for the RTC, but when I do A "getdate" the date stays the same when the hours exceed 24, I am using the api for the STM32F2 microcontroller, the APi supplied by ST .

Can I force a processor reset to update the date, as a hardware reset updates the date.

Answer (score 2):

The AIRCR register (address 0x0xE000ED0C) has a SYSRESETREQ bit (0x0004).  Setting this bit resets the processor.

See:
Application interrupt and reset control register (SCB_AIRCR)
PM0056
Programming manual
STM32F10xxx/20xxx/21xxx/L1xxxx
Cortex-M3 programming manual

Answer (score 0):

To answer the direct question, you can usually force a hardware reset on this kind of processor by letting the watchdog expire:

- If it's already configured to cause a reset, then just spin in a for(;;) {} loop until it expires
- If the watchdog is not yet configured, then configure it to cause a reset with a minimum timeout and then spin.

A watchdog reset is usually a pretty close approximation of a normal power-up hardware reset.

All that said, I would strongly recommend that you chase-down the problem with the RTC and don't distract yourself with some horrible reset hack.

Start by trying to get away from using whatever craptastic code ST have provided in the form of an 'API' - this kind of code tends to be written by interns with terrible hangovers, and is worth looking at for examples, but rarely good enough to actually be properly useful.  Trying to use it without understanding it is almost always just a painful way of delaying the moment when you have to open the datasheet/userguide for the chip and get to grips with how it works.

You don't say exactly what processor you're using, but page 559 of this may be useful:

http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00225773.pdf

Be absolutely clear that you've done each step of the process as there is some stuff about initialising the calendar which looks quite fiddly.